# remote sudo to root using plaintext then running commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ssh

would like to ssh into other client servers in the same subnet using a cleartext password then sudo to root to turn off commands and reboot. I am purposely not adding the ssh key. I've tried

```
ssh -tt [username]@[host] "sudo su -; service snmpd stop; reboot ";
```

How would I pass in the password at the login for both the username and the sudo?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this in the manner that most completely defies best practice?

Comment: Sounds like a task more suited for Ansible.

Comment: I agree, but that's an even heavier lift than `ssh-keygen && ssh-copy-id`, so..

Comment: True, but I have fallen in love with Ansible. And the more I use it and discover features, the more I like it.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly (:

Comment: well I would like to use this for one time use for a large group of client boxes and remove it after. I guess I could type out the password every time, so there is no need to pass in password in plaintext. Even having to type out the password every time would be a lot quicker than ssh into every box and running commands.  I am asking for this method because there are corporate policies to fill out papers to add ssh-keygen to the client boxes, that will take days to accomplish.

Comment: You can get permission to stop services on and reboot machines easier than you can to secure them with ssh keys?

Comment: I dont think they want this user to be able to passwordless login

Comment: Once you work out the password issue, you will want to change the sudo command to `sudo -s /bin/bash -c "service snmpd stop; reboot"`.

Comment: You do **not** need ssh-keygen installed on the client servers. You will however need to append your public key to `~username/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the client hosts.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** The answer being provided here should work. However, violates best practices. This answer also assumes that `sshpass` is available on the host where the command will be initiated. The user has noted it is going to be used one time, then removed.

```
sshpass -pPASSWORD ssh -tt [username]@[host] 'echo PASSWORD | sudo -S -s /bin/bash -c "service snmpd stop; reboot"'
```

At the very least, the user should be using key exchange for the ssh login, and allow the use to execute the desired commands via sudo with no password.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a program called sshpass to pass your ssh password.  It can be used like this:

```
SSHPASS='sshpassword'
remoterootpass='remoterootpass'

sshpass -e ssh user@host <'EOF'
su -
echo "$remoterootpass"
service snmpd stop
reboot
EOF
```

You could also put your remote commands in a shell script and call it like this:

```
SSHPASS='sshpassword'
cat myscript.sh | sshpass -e ssh user@host
```

Comment: And then your root password for the remote host in in plaintext in a file on disk, which is a fantastically terrible idea.

Comment: Yea the whole thing is a bad idea though.  To fix that issue though he could just allow his ssh user to sudo without a password.